# Allow multiple domain on postfix, Android bug?

Tags: android

I am using a dockerized mail server.
The mail server is load balanced using haproxy.
It's internal domain is serv-01.service.consul while it's external address is mail.mysite.com
I can't send mail from my android phone because of that, but it work on my laptop.

Is there a way to allow one or more domain in postfix?